# Twilio django send SMS and get answer using SMS as parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, twilio

In the twilio [example made in flask](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/employee-directory/python/flask#1), I can send an SMS and receive an answer using text and the SMS as the search parameter in the database. I need make this  but in a django project, my first option that I  thought make a django view with a parameter using a url with  for send the parameter, but  I see that is bad idea  because not is possible  can use the text of  SMS  as  parameter
This is a part of flask example

```
@app.route('/directory/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    query = request.form['Body']
```

I need make some similar to that view in django using django restframework but how I can get the Body (I think that the body is the text send in the SMS)
for use this as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.POST` to access the `form data`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        # all posted data
        data['body']

    # the rest of your view logic

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```